# Supporting DateTime with format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZ

Tags: c#, botframework

I am using Bot Framework, FormFlow.

When a field is created with type DateTime the FormFlow code is parsing the user text input as DateTime, which works great for most cases but it cannot parse inputs with the following template: 2017-05-16T14:32:27.5938714Z.
Our users are often copying exact dates from their logs so receiving this time template is a common scenario for our bot. Anything that can be done to support it?

```
        [Prompt("When did the issue begin (UTC)?")]
        [Template(TemplateUsage.NotUnderstood, "I'm sorry I couldn't understand the date you specified. Try something like '01-20-2017 17:05:03' or '2 days ago'")]
        [Optional]
        public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
```

Comment: So use `TryParse`, if it returns false, call `TryParseExact` with a format string, repeat until `TryParseExact` returns true or you run out of different formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem while building my own bot. I solved this by introducing a new variable into my form called `DateString`, of type `String`, and leave out the original `Date` object of type `DateTime`. This allowed the users to input any type of date format.

I created a validation method that would try to parse 2 types of input: either yyyy-MM-dd or dd-MM-yyyy. If the parse was successful I would use the date to fill in the `Date`property in my state and return a valid ValidationResult. If the date couldn't be parsed (or didn't live up to some other criteria) I would return an invalid ValidationResult. To the user

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [MSDN DateTime.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx)?
There is example with your format:

```
string[] formattedDates = { "2008-09-15T09:30:41.7752486-07:00", 
                               "2008-09-15T09:30:41.7752486Z",  
                               "2008-09-15T09:30:41.7752486",  
                               "2008-09-15T09:30:41.7752486-04:00", 
                               "Mon, 15 Sep 2008 09:30:41 GMT" };
   foreach (string formattedDate in formattedDates)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(formattedDate);
      DateTime roundtripDate = DateTime.Parse(formattedDate, null, 
                                              DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);                        
      Console.WriteLine("   With RoundtripKind flag: {0} {1} time.", 
                        roundtripDate, roundtripDate.Kind);                                          
      DateTime noRoundtripDate = DateTime.Parse(formattedDate, null, 
                                                DateTimeStyles.None);
      Console.WriteLine("   Without RoundtripKind flag: {0} {1} time.", 
                         noRoundtripDate, noRoundtripDate.Kind);                                          
   }         
// The example displays the following output:
//       2008-09-15T09:30:41.7752486-07:00
//          With RoundtripKind flag: 9/15/2008 9:30:41 AM Local time.
//          Without RoundtripKind flag: 9/15/2008 9:30:41 AM Local time.
//       2008-09-15T09:30:41.7752486Z
//          With RoundtripKind flag: 9/15/2008 9:30:41 AM Utc time.
//          Without RoundtripKind flag: 9/15/2008 2:30:41 AM Local time.
//       2008-09-15T09:30:41.7752486
//          With RoundtripKind flag: 9/15/2008 9:30:41 AM Unspecified time.
//          Without RoundtripKind flag: 9/15/2008 9:30:41 AM Unspecified time.
//       2008-09-15T09:30:41.7752486-04:00
//          With RoundtripKind flag: 9/15/2008 6:30:41 AM Local time.
//          Without RoundtripKind flag: 9/15/2008 6:30:41 AM Local time.
//       Mon, 15 Sep 2008 09:30:41 GMT
//          With RoundtripKind flag: 9/15/2008 9:30:41 AM Utc time.
//          Without RoundtripKind flag: 9/15/2008 2:30:41 AM Local time.
```

I believe MSDN, so you just need to use:

```
DateTime.Parse(formattedDate, null,DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind)
```

Comment: The question is in the context of FormFlow/BotFramework; is not just a C# parsing question